# Error installing knife-ec2

Tags: chef-infra, knife

While installing `knife-ec2`. I am getting below error.

> ERROR:  Error installing knife-ec2:
>           knife-ec2 requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

I updated the `ruby version 2.2.2` but still getting the same error.

Comment: If you're still getting that error, you either didn't successfully install Ruby 2.2.2 or have installed it parallel with another version of Ruby on your system that is still being preferred when you run the install command. How did you install Ruby 2.2.2? With a Ruby version management tool or some other way?

Comment: Update your chefdk installation and you'll be ok.

Comment: A lot of thanks to Tensibai and sixty 4bit. I updated my chefdk and it's work  fine.

Comment: @Tensibai Update chefdk  to which version I have # rpm -qa *chefdk*
chefdk-1.1.16-1.el6.x86_64 && # ruby --version
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @AshishKarpe ? what's the point of this comment ?

Comment: @Tensibai I also have same issue where I fell that I have latest chef dk version still not able to install knife-ec2 so just wanted to confirm which should be chefdk version ! as you have said above  Update your chefdk installation and you'll be ok. – Tensibai Feb 2 at 8:48 so do you want to reinstall chef dk or upgrade it to some specific version ?

Comment: @Ashish https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk

Comment: @Ashish sent too quick, when I say upgrade, it's to latest version, as usual un any problem, unless you have a valid reason to stick to a specific version, update to latest. If not, you have another question.

Comment: @Tensibai yes sir I have done it from same source Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6
License Information

Architecture: x86_64
SHA256: 9134c601cf079202bc4708eb1a04f49a672591cdeaf15acb1cbf762fa342add2
URL: https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chefdk/1.2.22/el/6/chefdk-1.2.22-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: @Ash the version you showed is 1.1.16, obviously not 1.2.22... Either your install failed or whatever, but you should better ask on http://discourse.chef.io I think

Comment: @Tensibai Ok got my mistake thanks a lot sir sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around this is to install [rvm](http://rvm.io/):

1. `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`
2. `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Then, install the proper ruby version: `rvm install --default 2.2`

Now, you should be running the proper ruby version; you can confirm with `ruby -v`

Install `knife-ec2`: `gem install knife-ec2`; it will resolve all the dependencies which will also install ChefDK for you.